# Run Gatling SBT without generating reports

Tags: sbt, gatling, scala-gatling, gatling-plugin

Is it possible to run the [gatling-sbt](https://gatling.io/docs/current/extensions/sbt_plugin/) plugin without generating the reports at the end?

I can't find anything that mentions this in the documentation or elsewhere online.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After looking into Gatling further, I discovered it's actually possible to prevent the simulation itself from generating the reports through [configuration](https://gatling.io/docs/current/general/configuration#gatling-conf):

`gatling.charting.noReports = true`

This is set to false by [default](https://github.com/gatling/gatling/blob/a34d700ac29b150da65cc73c8298b6bc62320fa1/gatling-core/src/main/resources/gatling-defaults.conf#L42).

Just to confirm that the sbt testOptions setting mentioned by @George Leung above also worked, but I thought this approach was neater.

Answer (score 2):

according to [the documentation](https://gatling.io/docs/current/general/configuration) you can use the option: `–no-reports`

Comment: Indeed it does, completely missed that... Thanks

Comment: Actually that is for gatling, not sbt-gatling, unfortunately

Comment: In sbt: `testOptions in Gatling += Argument(GatlingPlugin.gatlingTestFramework, "--no-reports")`. BTW in the documentation `--` was as rendered as `–`.